# Can a MOC3032M optocoupler be used to generate a DC PWM signal?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, control, opto-isolator, triac

I'm trying to make a circuit that can output an 80 Hz PWM signal. I'm planning to use an Arduino to switch an optocoupler that will control the duty cycle.

Here is my circuit:

[image]

After building the circuit, I used a multimeter to measure the output voltage and frequency. The voltage was 11.5 V and the frequency was 0 Hz.

I also changed R1 and R2 to 1 Mohm resistors. The output voltage was 3.64 V and output frequency was 79.41 Hz.

My questions are:

1. Why is the multimeter showing a different result with different resistance? In my understanding, it should provide a constant voltage and frequency with different resistance.
2. Is MOC3032M suitable to control a DC PWM signal? If not, is there any optocoupler suitable for the task? After doing some research, I realize the zero crossing detection in my optocoupler could interfere with DC signal every time it got turned on and off, but I couldn't find a detailed explanation of this topic.

Here is my Arduino code if it helps.

```c++
    int relayPin = 8; // Assign the relay to digital pin 8
    
    void setup() {
      pinMode(relayPin, OUTPUT); // Set the relay pin as an output
    }
    
    void loop() {
      digitalWrite(relayPin, HIGH); // Turn the relay on
      delayMicroseconds(3750); // On time: 30% of 12.5 ms (80 Hz cycle)
    
      digitalWrite(relayPin, LOW); // Turn the relay off
    
      delayMicroseconds(8750); // Off time: 70% of 12.5 ms
    }
```

Here is the [MOC3032M datasheet](https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/rf0pcmnkv6/FAIR-S-A0002364056-1.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw).

Comment: Triac is not used as DC switch. Use optotransistor.

Answer (score 3):

The [MOC3023M](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/MOC3032M-196149.pdf) is most unsuitable for your project. It has a TRIAC output stage which is designed for **AC** supplies and, to complicate further, it has zero-cross switching. I have written a little about these on [Opto-triacs and zero-cross detection](http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-triacs-zero-cross-work/).

[image]

*Figure 1. Internals of a zero-cross detection circuit based on the similar [G3MB-202P](https://www.openhacks.com/uploadsproductos/g3mb-ssr-datasheet.pdf) with 5 V input.*

TRIACs have the characteristic that, once switched on, they stay on until the current through the TRIAC falls below the hold-on value. (That means something external to the TRIAC is required to turn it off. Usually that's the zero-crossing of the mains voltage.)

For your application you need an opto-isolator with a transistor output.